# IntelliJ after update i can't load dart/flutter plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I updated IntelliJ community version via IntelliJ toolbox and now i can't run my code. Flutter doctor says that everything is ok.
In IntelliJ -> Settings -> Plugins, installed -> i don't see flutter or dart plugins and in plugins market is endless loading.
I tried uninstall but the problem persists

[image: situation]

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. Marketplace [loads just fine here](https://i.imgur.com/xSrrADD.png). [Contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) for help.

Comment: At the end of idea.log file i got "[  77427]   INFO - .ide.plugins.PluginManagerMain - Main plugin repository is not available ('Cannot create directory C:\Users\Milo?\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\192.6817.14.plugins'). Please check your network settings."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3913) in the Toolbox application .

The workaround is to edit `-Didea.plugins.path=` in `Help` | **Edit Custom VM Options** to move plug-ins folder outside of the user's home directory.